# Как перенаправить весь трафик через другой ПК?

Tags: ip, маршрутизация, vpn

Как можно пропускать весь трафик с одного ПК(не важно на какой ОС) через другой ПК(с Win 10)?

То есть, чтобы я не делал со своего ноута(и не важно откуда) весь трафик должен отправляться на мой домашний ПК, а далее в сеть. Также, везде должно указываться, что делаю я всё со своего домашнего ПК.

Вопрос чисто теоретический. Знаю, что как-то можно такое сделать, но информации не нашёл...

PS Пробовал через VPN в винде, но оно не пашет... Выдаёт ошибку 800

[Ссылка на видео с примером, который пробовал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKs2OQwI68c)

Comment: Прокси. Гуглите.

Comment: Код ошибки приложения, сервиса, драйвера? Даже если клиента, то много причин для ошибки: не все промежуточные протоколы связи разрешены для входящего соединения до VPN-сервера, неверно сконфигурированы протоколы безопасности (сертификаты, даты времени и т.д.), неправильно сконфигурирован клиент, соединение "режется" на стороне провайдера. В общем, Ваш `вопрос требует уточнений`: почему Вам не хватит технологий удаленного рабочего стола, какой протокол был указан для входящих соединений, все ли порты были открыты на фаерволах и опубликованы на межсетевом шлюзе и т.д.

Comment: @eanmos, я знаю что он  есть, только вот ничего не вышло у меня...  И я попросил помощи ссылкой как развернуть прокси-сервер или сами шаги расписать